# Prevent jquery autocomplete after a certain number of characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I want to prevent jquery autocomplete after a certain number of characters.

The purpose is, I've a list of order numbers which has a suffix in last and that is always known. Each order no. is of 12 digits with 3 digits as known suffix. I want to start auto complete after 5 characters and that I achieved using `minLength: 5`, but I not able to specify the max number as 8.

Since the last 3 digits are always known, I want it to search it only for first 8 digits as if you know the first 9 digits then you know the complete order no. already.

I've tried using `maxLength:8` but it doesn't work. Autocomplete fires even after 8 digits and further.

Please help. Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: simple logic would be to disable the auto complete once it reaches the max limit & enable it back when its under limit. just toggle based on limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `source` option as a function :

```
$('#myInput').autocomplete({
    ...
    source: function(pattern, response){
      if (pattern.length > 8) {
        //don't do anything
        return;
      }

      //else : fetch your data, and call the 'response' callback
      $.ajax({
          url: 'my/autcomplete/url',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {"pattern": pattern}
          success: function(data){
              // build a string array form your data,
              // or an array of {label, value} objects (see the doc)
              response(data);
          }
      });
    }
```

See the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

Comment: hey, thanks for pointing to the documentation, I did go there before but didn't care about about the request param. It contains a property term, did the trick. Edited your answer with that. now it's working perfectly. Thanks.